# Html5 Canvas Transformation Algorithm - Finding object coordinates after applying transformation

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, html5-canvas, coordinate-transformation

On html5 canvas I am drawing objects (rectangle, circle, etc...), these objects have transformation properties like scale, skew, rotation etc... These objects can be nested.

Problem occurs when I after applying transformations, I want to find exact x, y coordinate of given object, but its going over my head.

To all experts who is into interactive computer graphics; please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630594/html5-canvas-transformation-matrix

Comment: No this is not duplicate, it is similar to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844525/get-position-on-canvas-after-rotating-translating-and-restoring) but not same . I am looking for similar answer for my queries. But thanks your reference link also helped...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All affine transformations in 2D can be expressed as a matrix of the form:

```
    [ a  c  dx ]
T = [ b  d  dy ]
    [ 0  0   1 ]
```

This could be expressed with the method `context.transform(a, b, c, d, dx, dy);`.

When applied to some coordinate, `(x,y)`, you first have to add a third coordinate, which is always `1`: `<x, y, 1>`. Then you can multiply the transformation matrix to get the result:

```
[ a*x + c*y + dx ]
[ b*x + d*y + dy ]
[       1        ]
```

If you get anything other than '1' in the last coordinate, you have to divide the vector by it.

---

To go the other way, you have to invert the matrix:

```
[ d/M  -c/M  (c*dy - d*dx)/M ]
[ b/M   a/M  (b*dx - a*dy)/M ]
[  0     0          1        ]
```

where `M` is `(a*d - b*c)`.

---

Multiple transformations could be applied in sequence, by multiplying their matrices. The order of the multiplications are important.

---

```
context.translate(dx,dy) <==> context.transform( 1,  0,  0,  1, dx, dy)
context.rotate(θ)        <==> context.transform( c,  s, -s,  c,  0,  0)
context.scale(sx,sy)     <==> context.transform(sx,  0,  0, sy,  0,  0)
```

where `c = Math.cos(θ)` and `s = Math.sin(θ)`

---

If you got some coordinate `(x,y)` in object-space, and you want to know where it will end up on the screen, you apply the transformation to it.

If you got some coordinate `(x,y)` on the screen, and you want to know which point on the object that is, you multiply by the inverse of the transformation.

Comment: this is somewhat confusing layout of the matrix elements, as setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f) in the canvas API is laid out: [a, c, e \n b, d, f \n 0 0 1], see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform

Comment: @TomLarkworthy Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: What method are you using to get the original coordinate? I am using ```var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();``` ```var xcoord = (event.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.widht /rect.widht)``` ```return newX = xcoord *a + ycoord*c + e``` but that gives the wrong newX.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Larkworthy's answer is perfect, but with a minor typo.
Correct formula to invert the matrix is:

```
[  d/M  -c/M  (c*dy - d*dx)/M ]
[ -b/M   a/M  (b*dx - a*dy)/M ]
[   0     0          1        ]
```